# How do i call functions of a class - Swift

Tags: ios, swift

Im still trying to learn this portion of things. I've looked around and read a few questions about it but truthfully I dont understand any of it.

I've got a circle class that creates and draws a circle

```
class CircleView: UIView {
var circleLayer: CAShapeLayer!
var isAnimating = false
override init(frame: CGRect) {
    let fColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor





    super.init(frame: frame)
    self.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear

    // Use UIBezierPath as an easy way to create the CGPath for the layer.
    // The path should be the entire circle.
    let circlePath = UIBezierPath(arcCenter: CGPoint(x: frame.size.width / 2.0, y: frame.size.height / 2.0), radius: (frame.size.width - 10)/2, startAngle: 0.0, endAngle: CGFloat(M_PI * 2.0), clockwise: true)

    // Setup the CAShapeLayer with the path, colors, and line width
    circleLayer = CAShapeLayer()
    circleLayer.path = circlePath.cgPath
   circleLayer.fillColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
    circleLayer.strokeColor = UIColor.init(rgbColorCodeRed: 230, green: 226, blue: 218, alpha: 1).cgColor
    circleLayer.lineWidth = 9.0;

    // Don't draw the circle initially
    circleLayer.strokeEnd = 0.0

    // Add the circleLayer to the view's layer's sublayers
    layer.addSublayer(circleLayer)
}

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
}



func setCircleClockwise(){
    let circlePath = UIBezierPath(arcCenter: CGPoint(x: frame.size.width / 2.0, y: frame.size.height / 2.0), radius: (frame.size.width - 10)/2, startAngle: 0.0, endAngle: CGFloat(M_PI * 2.0), clockwise: true)
    self.circleLayer.removeFromSuperlayer()
    self.circleLayer = formatCirle(circlePath: circlePath)
    self.layer.addSublayer(self.circleLayer)
}

func setCircleCounterClockwise(){
    let circlePath = UIBezierPath(arcCenter: CGPoint(x: frame.size.width / 2.0, y: frame.size.height / 2.0), radius: (frame.size.width - 10)/2, startAngle: 0.0, endAngle: CGFloat(M_PI * 2.0), clockwise: false)
    self.circleLayer.removeFromSuperlayer()
    self.circleLayer = formatCirle(circlePath: circlePath)
    self.layer.addSublayer(self.circleLayer)
}

func formatCirle(circlePath: UIBezierPath) -> CAShapeLayer{
    let circleShape = CAShapeLayer()
    circleShape.path = circlePath.cgPath
    circleShape.fillColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
    circleShape.strokeColor = UIColor.init(rgbColorCodeRed: 230, green: 226, blue: 218, alpha: 1).cgColor
    circleShape.lineWidth = 9.0;
    circleShape.strokeEnd = 0.0
    return circleShape
}

func animate(duration: TimeInterval){
    self.isAnimating = true
    self.animateCircleFull(duration: 1)
}

func endAnimate(){
    self.isAnimating = false
}

func animateCircleFull(duration: TimeInterval) {
    if self.isAnimating{
        CATransaction.begin()
        let animation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "strokeEnd")
        animation.duration = duration
        animation.fromValue = 0
        animation.toValue = 1
        animation.timingFunction = CAMediaTimingFunction(name: kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut)
        circleLayer.strokeEnd = 1.0
        CATransaction.setCompletionBlock {
            self.setCircleCounterClockwise()
            self.animateCircleEmpty(duration: duration)
        }
        // Do the actual animation
        circleLayer.add(animation, forKey: "animateCircle")
        CATransaction.commit()
    }
}

func animateCircleEmpty(duration: TimeInterval){
    if self.isAnimating{
        CATransaction.begin()
        let animation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "strokeEnd")
        animation.duration = duration
        animation.fromValue = 1
        animation.toValue = 0
        animation.timingFunction = CAMediaTimingFunction(name: kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut)
        circleLayer.strokeEnd = 0
        CATransaction.setCompletionBlock {
            self.setCircleClockwise()
            self.animateCircleFull(duration: duration)
        }
        // Do the actual animation
        circleLayer.add(animation, forKey: "animateCircle")
        CATransaction.commit()
    }
}
```

Which is being called from my viewController with the below function. It all works fine but what i cant work out is how do i go about calling the endAnimation function on the same circle?

```
func addCircleView() {
    let diceRoll = CGFloat(Int(arc4random_uniform(7))*50)
    var circleWidth = CGFloat(100)
    var circleHeight = circleWidth
    var bgColor: UIColor = UIColor.init(rgbColorCodeRed: 230, green: 226, blue: 218, alpha: 1)

    // Create a new CircleView
    let circleView = CircleView(frame: CGRect(x: self.view.frame.width/2, y: self.view.frame.height-110, width: circleWidth, height: circleHeight))
    //let test = CircleView(frame: CGRect(x: diceRoll, y: 0, width: circleWidth, height: circleHeight))
    cv = circleView
    view.addSubview(circleView)

    // Animate the drawing of the circle over the course of 1 second
    circleView.animate(duration: 1)
    let imageName = "ButtonBackground.png"
    let image = UIImage(named: imageName)
    let imageView = UIImageView(image: image!)
    imageView.frame = CGRect(x: self.view.frame.width/2, y: self.view.frame.height-110, width: 100, height: 100)
    view.addSubview(imageView)
    view.bringSubview(toFront: circleView)
}
```

Comment: You don’t have any endAnimation() function, it’s endAnimate(). I hope you’re trying to call the right function.

Answer (score 0):

For calling endAnimation function on the same circle you have to declare property in your ViewController class.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

var circleView = CircleView()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.addCircleView()
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

func addCircleView() {
    let diceRoll = CGFloat(Int(arc4random_uniform(7))*50)
    var circleWidth = CGFloat(100)
    var circleHeight = circleWidth
    var bgColor: UIColor = UIColor.init(rgbColorCodeRed: 230, green: 226, blue: 218, alpha: 1)

    // Create a new CircleView
    self.circleView = CircleView(frame: CGRect(x: self.view.frame.width/2, y: self.view.frame.height-110, width: circleWidth, height: circleHeight))
    //let test = CircleView(frame: CGRect(x: diceRoll, y: 0, width: circleWidth, height: circleHeight))
    cv = circleView
    view.addSubview(circleView)

    // Animate the drawing of the circle over the course of 1 second
    circleView.animate(duration: 1)
    let imageName = "ButtonBackground.png"
    let image = UIImage(named: imageName)
    let imageView = UIImageView(image: image!)
    imageView.frame = CGRect(x: self.view.frame.width/2, y: self.view.frame.height-110, width: 100, height: 100)
    view.addSubview(imageView)
    view.bringSubview(toFront: circleView)
   //now you are able to call endAnimation function
   self.circleView.endAnimate()

   }

}
```